# Need help to check SSH list for alive tunnel

Tags: bash, ssh, tunnel

I have a list of ssh servers runing linux and I would like to run test on them to see if the ssh tunnel is working. I have them saved like:

```
root:mypass:10.0.0.1
root:mypass:10.0.0.2
root:mypass:10.0.0.3
```

Is there any way to run a script like `./check list.txt` and give me output for those who can do ssh tunnel? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what the tunnel is? What is the test about?

Comment: Tunnel is using ssh ip as socks inside a browser so I get to use my other server's ip inside my browser.

Comment: For Socks, I'd try `curl -x`. See `man curl`.

Comment: That wouldn't help for checking a ssh list if tunnel is working..